# unique schema not working mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having a situation in which I have defined username and email as unique in my model but whenever I try to insert the duplicate username/email in the database it gets inserted.

here is my model

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique:true
},
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique:true
}})
```

here is my code in which I insert the data

```
        let user = new User(req.body);

    user.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false });
        } else {
            res.json({ result, success: true });
            sendmail(req.body.email,req.body.username,verificationcode);
        }
    });
```

Comment: restart your mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. So Try using mongoose unique validator in your model

```
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
```

Or try to delete the table so that mongo recreates them

Answer (score 0):

I would query for the user existence then use an if statement as follow:

```
User.findOne({email:req.body.email,username:req.body.username},(err, user)=>{
if(!user){ 
let newUser = new User bla bla bla 
}else{
res.json({message:"User already exists."})
}
```